# Custom routing: 2 step user enrollment - second step with no route to patch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to enrol a new user. For this I have 2 steps. First I generate a form to get all the data of the new user:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.label :street %>
      <%= f.text_field :street %>
      <%= f.label :hnumber %>
      <%= f.text_field :hnumber %>
      <%= f.label :bus %>
      <%= f.text_field :bus %>
      <%= f.label :zipcode %>
      <%= f.text_field :zipcode %>
      <%= f.label :city %>
      <%= f.text_field :city %>
      <%= f.label :country %>
      <%= f.text_field :country %>
      <%= f.label :nationality %>
      <%= f.text_field :nationality %>
      <%= f.submit "Add user", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

This goes to the controller:

```
   def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Added user #{@user[:id]}"
      render 'getfingerprintid'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Second step is to scan the 10 fingers of the user wit han browser applet that communicates with a scanner. For this I created a new route so I would get the view with this applet (I made a simplified view).

**route:**

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'getUserid'
    end
  end
  match '/getUserid',  to: 'users#getfingerprintid',         via: 'post'
```

**view:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Get fingerprintid) %>
<h1>New ID</h1>


    <%= form_for(@user, url: getfingerprintid_path) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :finger %>
      <%= f.text_field :finger %>
      <%= f.submit "getfingerprintid", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This last step tries to patch. Which I assume is not wrong but I get as error: **No route matches [PATCH] "/getUserid"**

**Now my questions:**

- How do I resolve this issue?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Update:

Added rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action

    match_users GET    /users/match(.:format)       users#match
getUserid_users GET    /users/getUserid(.:format)   users#getUserid
          users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
                 PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
        newuser GET    /newuser(.:format)           users#new
      matchuser POST   /matchuser(.:format)         users#match
       getUserid POST   /getUserid(.:format)          users#getUserid
        adduser POST   /adduser(.:format)           users#finger
       userdata POST   /userdata(.:format)          users#add
```

Update(2):

Resourceful routing should clean up te mess I'm making. (http://blog.jamesalmond.com/resourceful-routing-with-rails/). This answers what I should be doing in a clean way. But still would like to know what went wrong in my original setup :)

Comment: update your question with results from rake routes.

Answer (score 0):

Update your route file  :

```
resources :users do
  match '/getUserid',  to: 'donors#getfingerprintid', via: :post
end
```

Comment: error: undefined local variable or method `getUserid_path' (BTW donors should be users typpo in my orginal post which I updated)

Comment: i mean post your relevant match inside resources

Comment: And got another error as stated in my precious comment :)